# Batch file with spaces in variables/filenames in text file

Tags: variables, batch-file, spaces

I'm not at all educated on coding so you'll have to excuse any poor terminology!

I've picked a few pieces of code for a batch file from around the web (some of it from this site) and I've attempted to rewrite some of it to suit my needs.

It creates a new directory, then looks through another directory and all its subdirectories for filenames in a .txt list, and then copies those files to the directory created at the beginning. Any files that are not found from the list are written into another text file to keep track of anything that is missing.

The code is:

```
md 00FoundImages

set LIST=%cd%\imagelist.txt
set FILESPATH=%cd%\testimages
set DEST=%cd%\00FoundImages

for /f "delims=" %%x in (%LIST%) do (forfiles /p %FILESPATH% /s /m %%x* /c "cmd /c move /y @path %DEST%\@file" 2>>errors.txt)
```

This works fine under most conditions, except for when:

1. A filename in the text file contains a space
2. The path to the directory in which the batch file resides contains a space (or other special character)

I've tried enclosing in quotes like so:

```
set FILELIST="%cd%\imagelist.txt"
set FILESPATH="%cd%\testimages"
set DESTPATH="%cd%\00FoundImages"
```

This fails at the `forfiles`command as soon as a space is found in the directory name.

I've tried enclosing the variable when it is used in quotes like so:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ("%LIST%") do (forfiles /p "%FILESPATH%" /s /m %%x* /c "cmd /c move /y @path "%DEST%\@file"" 2>>errors.txt)
```

When I run the batch file from a directory called 'testing - Copy', I get the error written into my errors.txt file

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

This is the print of what is occurring:

```
E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>md 00FoundImages
A subdirectory or file 00FoundImages already exists.

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>set LIST=E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\imagelist.txt

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>set FILESPATH=E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\testimages

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>set DEST=E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\00FoundImages

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>for /F "delims=" %x in ("E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\imagelist.txt") do (forfiles /p "E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\testimages" /s /m %x* /c "cmd /c move /y @path "E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\00FoundImages\@file""  2>>errors.txt )

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>(forfiles /p "E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\testimages" /s /m E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\imagelist.txt* /c "cmd /c move /y @path "E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\00FoundImages\@file""  2>>errors.txt )

E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

From the research I've done I can see questions of this nature get asked a lot - apologies for adding to the pile but with my limited knowledge I'm afraid I'm simply unable to fix this issue on my own!

Comment: Filenames (or any other parameter) with spaces MUST be enclosed in quotes. `"c:\Program files\Office"`. Space delimits parameters unless in quotes.

Comment: I have tried enclosing the variables in quotes but this does not work. I've done it multiple different ways, enclosing the variables at the `set` stage and the `for /f` stage

Comment: You have to show how you enclosed them in quotes by editing your question.

Comment: Apologies - I've updated the question.

Comment: The quotes go around the variable when using it, as it is the wrong time to use quotes (as you are adding to the path). `Set cat=dog` and `Type "%cat%\NewFolder"`

Comment: Ok I've just tried this (no luck) and updated my post with how I did it and the error returned.

Comment: Did you remove the quotes from the `set` commands when you added the quotes to the command itself. It should be printing on screen what it is doing (no one here has your file structure). Copy and paste that. If you have an `Echo Off` in the batch comment it out (`rem` for remark).

Comment: Yes I have removed the quotes from the `set`commands. I've copied the print into my original post.

Comment: the quotes should be around both the variable name and value like this `set "FILELIST=%cd%\imagelist.txt"`

Comment: This gives the same error as not having quotes there at all.

Comment: The set command isn't the problem. `set` accepts spaces on both sides of the `=` sign so both variable's names and values can contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid troubles with spaces in paths and file names, use quotes. But you need to be carefull when it comes to `forfiles`, because all path- and file-name-related `@`-variables are expanded to values already enclosed within `""`, so it can easily happen to have values double-quoted.

I would give this a try:

```
md "%cd%\00FoundImages"

set "LIST=%cd%\imagelist.txt"
set "FILESPATH=%cd%\testimages"
set "DEST=%cd%\00FoundImages"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%LIST%") do (
    forfiles /p "%FILESPATH%" /s /m "%%x*" /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE cd /d 0x22%DEST%0x22 & move /y @path @file" 2>>errors.txt
)
```

What I did:

- improved syntax of `set` so that the entire assignment expression is enclosed within `""`; this avoids trouble with some special characters, but the quotes are *not* part of the variable values;
- quoted `%LIST%`, so I had to add the `usebackq` option to `for /f`, because it would treat the value of variable `%LIST%` as a literal string rather than a file otherwise;
- the path after `/p` as well as the pattern after `/m` of `forfiles` are enclosed in parentheses; here it is very important that the path after `/p` is *not* terminated by a `\`, because this would be interpreted as an escape character by `forfiles` to escape the closing quote `"`; <s>if you cannot assure that `%FILESPATH%` fulfils that criterion, write `/p "%FILESPATH%\."` instead;</s> *edit: the last statement is wrong!*
- the `@path` variable expands to an already quoted string, so everything is fine with it;
- the tricky part is the destination file `%DEST%\@file` from your original code, because `@file` expands to an already quoted string, so the result would be something like `\...\00FoundImages\"FoundImage 1.png"`, for instance; so quoting the entire expression like `0x22%DEST%\@file0x22`<sup>1</sup> would lead to `"\...\00FoundImages\"FoundImage 1.png""`, hence the file name `FoundImage 1.png` appears unquoted to the command interpreter; using `0x22%DEST%0x22\@file`<sup>1</sup> would lead to `"\...\00FoundImages"\"FoundImage 1.png"`, which does not harm many commands, but could impact some, and it is simply not beautiful; to overcome this, simply change to the directory `%DEST%` first by `cd /d 0x22%DEST%0x22`<sup>1</sup>, so it is stated alone, then use `@file` only for the `move` command line;
- finally, `forfiles` returns both matching files *and* directories, so to ensure that there are only files processed, I implemented an `if` query;

---

<sub>1)... the `0x22` expression stands for a `"` character in `forfiles /C` command expressions and represents its character code in hexadecimal notation; I prefer this way of specifying quotes, because the other option, `\"`, might impact the command line interpreter as it does not support the backslash-escaping and therefore it recognises the quotation mark, which might alter its behaviour unintentionally.</sub>

Comment: Seems to be working! Great explanation too - I understand better what is happening here. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ("%LIST%") do (forfiles /p "%FILESPATH%" /s /m %%x* /c "cmd /c move /y @path \"%DEST%\@file\"" 2>>errors.txt)
```

Quotes within the quotes that is the command `forfiles` runs have to be escaped with a backslash. But not other quotes like starting folder.

Comment: This still produces the same error...
`ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-'.`
...the dash being part of the directory name (testing - Copy)

Comment: You need quotes (without a backslash) around `%%X` in the `forfiles` commandline. It never hurts to put in quotes even if not needed. Any string that does or may (in the case of variables) contain spaces needs to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Using `for /f "delims=" %%x in ("%LIST%") do (forfiles /p "%FILESPATH%" /s /m "%%x"* /c "cmd /c move /y @path \"%DEST%\@file\"" 2>>errors.txt)`

results in

`ERROR: Files of type "E:\ImageAutomationStuff\testing - Copy\imagelist.txt*" not found. `

Comment: `*` is part of your parameter. Use `/m "%%x*"`.

Comment: This returns the exact same error, no matter which side of the wildcard I put the quote.

EDIT: I should also add, this no longer works at all even if the directory has no spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not understand why do you nest `FORFILES` loop in another (`FOR /F`) loop, next code snippet should do the trick:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%LIST%") do (
  forfiles /p "%FILESPATH%" /s /m "%%~nxx" /c "cmd /c ECHO move /y @path \"%DEST%\"\@file" 2>>errors.txt
)
```

Note:

- double quotes in `"%FILESPATH%"` and `"%%~nxx"`;
- escaped double quotes in `\"%DEST%\"`;
- plain `@path` and `@file` as those `FORFILES` command variables are already double quoted;
- maybe that you need to reformulate `/m "%%~nxx"` file mask (I use [`%%~nxx` file name and extension](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) because I don't know `%LIST%` file content and suppose a list of fully qualified file names);
- *important*: `move` command is merely *displayed* for debugging purposes; remove preceding `ECHO` to make it operational, no sooner than debugged.